# How to check nullable int against nullable enum in unit test assertion?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Writing some integration tests we want to compare values read from the DB (int) against the object being used (enum field on a DTO).

So conceptually `dto.EnumValue.Should().Be((MyEnum)expectedIntValue)`

However these are both nullable. I know how to compare two nullable values of the same type but I can't see an obvious way to compare nullable int against nullable enum.

So far we ended up with:

```
if(dto.EnumValue == null)
 expectedValue.Should().BeNull();
else
 dto.EnumValue.Should().Be((MyEnum)expectedIntValue.Value);
```

I feel there is surely a way to do this better, adding logic to unit test expectations is not great?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert one value to match the datatype of the other. So either:

```
enumValue.Should().Be((Foo?)intValue);
```

Or:

```
((int?)enumValue).Should().Be(intValue);
```

Comment: ah cast as nullable, thanks